# Scala val concurrency

Tags: scala

If I have an expression such as:

```
block 1 {
   val x = 5
}
```

and then I do:

```
block 2 {
   val z = x + 5
   val y = x + 4
   val a = x * 2
   val b = x / 5
}
```

Are the statements in `block 2` executed concurrently?

How would changing `block 1` to `lazy val x = 5` effect the execution of `block 2`?

How would changing `block 1` to `var x = 5` effect the execution `block 2`?

Comment: No. Not concurrently - from top to bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are the statements in block 2 executed concurrently?

No. They are executed sequentially.

> How would changing block 1 to `lazy val x = 5` effect the execution of block 2?

Initializing `z` would take slightly longer because it would need to wait for `x` to initialize. And then it would proceed as normal.

> How would changing block 1 to `var x = 5` effect the execution block 2?

As is, it wouldn't.

To get them to execute concurrently you would have to do so on different threads, preferably using [`Future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/?_ga=1.8468725.1939486482.1433104516#scala.concurrent.Future).

Comment: `var val x` wouldn't compile.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Heh, I didn't actually read past the `var`. My brain assumed correct syntax. I'll edit out the error, assuming that's what was intended.

Comment: @m-z, fixed the error. I probably copied and pasted and my eyes missed the syntax. Thanks.